Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndro
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
Android resource linking failed
error: resource style/Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar (aka com.example.calendar:style/Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar) not found.
error: resource style/Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar (aka com.example.calendar:style/Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar) not found.
error: failed linking references.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

this error occurs while executing file on emulator and phone
I added the NoActionBar in the styles.xml file still the same error

Try this by adding this line to gradle.properties.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m

